# Назначение переменной из формы в контроллер

Tags: php, opencart, controller

PHP только начинаю постигать, посему не могу понять, как поймать select, который будет иметь value 1...3.

```html
<select name="custom_field[address][1]">
  <option value="1">Сочи</option>
  <option value="2">Крым</option>
  <option value="3">Новосиб</option>
</select>
```

Пробую так:

```
$data['region'] = array(
      'sochi' => ($this->request->get['custom_field[address][1]'] == 1),
      'krym'  => ($this->request->get['custom_field[address][1]'] == 2),
      'nsk'   => ($this->request->get['custom_field[address][1]'] == 3)
    );
```

Далее делаю условие для значения value:

```
if ($region == $sochi) {
        $data['region_a'] = ('***@gmail.com');
    }
```

И подставляю в нужное место:

```
$mail = new Mail($region_a);
```

И получаю ошибку о не назначенной переменной:

```
    SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
OK
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: custom_field[address][1] in <b>/catalog/controller/mail/order.php</b> on line <b>449</b>
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: custom_field[address][1] in <b>/catalog/controller/mail/order.php</b> on line <b>450</b>
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: custom_field[address][1] in <b>/catalog/controller/mail/order.php</b> on line <b>451</b>
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: sochi in <b>/catalog/controller/mail/order.php</b> on line <b>454</b>
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: region in <b>/catalog/controller/mail/order.php</b> on line <b>454</b>
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: region_a in <b>/catalog/controller/mail/order.php</b> on line <b>458</b>
<b>Notice</b>: Error: Could not load mail adaptor ! in <b>/system/library/mail.php</b> on line <b>36</b>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Откуда у вас появилась эта `$region_a` переменная?
 Вы же объявили массив с ключом 
`$data['region_a']`, значит и в конструктор должны передавать его значение т.е.

`$mail = new Mail($data['region_a']);`

Comment: Спасибо, я вас понял. Теперь не могу понять, как присвоить переменную из селекта.

Comment: Ну как я понял вы сейчас пытаетесь изучить какой то фреймворк или cms. Но я вам советую начать с азов. Для начало изучите, что это за переменные  $_GET и $_POST, а правки  в коде я бы сделал '<option value="sochi">Сочи</option>' вместо 1,2,3 в `value`  поставил бы название городов и уже делал бы в условии так
 `if ($this->request->get['custom_field[address][1]'] == 'sochi') {
        $data['region_a'] = ('***@gmail.com');
    }

$mail = new Mail($data['region_a']);
`

Comment: Да. К сожалению, желание познать php появилось именно с готовых cms. В данном случае - opencart и реализация нереализованного функционала.